# html video tag not playing m3u8 file when serve by golang server

Tags: html, go, video, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have generated the m3u8 file (index.m3u8) from a video and I want to play it on HTML.
Basically, I have a golang server which will send the index.m3u8 to the video tag in html5 to play it when http://127.0.0.1:8200/play is called.

my golang file :

```
package main

import(
"fmt"
"net/http"
"html/template"
)


func serveHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.html"))

    tmpl.Execute(w, "videosource/index.m3u8")

}


func main(){

fmt.Println("begin listening to port 8200")

server := http.Server{
    Addr: "127.0.0.1:8200",
}
http.HandleFunc("/play",serveHandler)
server.ListenAndServe()

}
```

this is my html file:

```
<html>
  <body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@canary"></script>
<video id="video" controls autoplay></video>
<script>
if(Hls.isSupported())
{
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('{{.}}');
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function()
    {
        video.play();
    });
}
else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl'))
{
    video.src = '{{.}}';
    video.addEventListener('canplay',function()
    {
        video.play();
    });
}
</script>
```

the error i get in console when i go to the url (http://127.0.0.1:8200/play)  is

```
videosource/index.m3u8:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

To check that the error is not caused by path error, I tried to replace the `'{{.}}'` in HTML with the full path ('videosource/index.m3u8') and it works perfectly.

Please guide me and show me what's wrong with my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set your header to the right type.
Try something like this:

```
func serveHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/x-mpegURL")

  tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.html"))
  tmpl.Execute(w, "videosource/index.m3u8")

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It works. however, there is another error pop up
    hls.js@latest:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///home/jetherng/go/src/stream/%7B%7B.%7D%7D' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Any idea about this?

Comment: you have to enable cross origin (CORS) on your webserver. Look here https://flaviocopes.com/golang-enable-cors/